# A word that describes two opposing effects rooted in the same thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, when a law might cause a good effect to the poor but a bad effect to the rich.

Comment: [*Double-edged sword*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%E2%80%93edged%20sword), perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are asking what word would describe that. Some possibilities would be polar effect or polarizing. Also, possibly dichotomy and dilemma. These examples are based on the example that you gave.